# Chat Server Application not working using C programming

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have been trying to create a chat server and client model (where the server reads the message sent by client and replies back with a hello message) using C programming, but my code isn't working.

Here's my code:

**Server side code**
https://cl1p.net/server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PORT 22341
#define MAXLINE 1024
int main(){
    int sockfd;
    int clientfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE+1];
    if ((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0){
        perror("Socket creation failed at server end");
        exit(1);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if ((bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0)){
        perror("Error while binding at server side");
        exit(2);
    }
    int len=sizeof(servaddr);
    while (1){
        memset(buffer,0,strlen(buffer));
        listen(sockfd,5);
        accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,&len);
        recv(clientfd,buffer,MAXLINE,0); 
        if (strncmp(buffer,"Exit",4)==0){
            printf ("Server exiting \n");
            break;
        }
        send(clientfd,(char *)"Hello",MAXLINE,0);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    close(clientfd); 
}
```

**Client Code:**

https://cl1p.net/client1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PORT 22341
#define MAXLINE 1024
int main(){
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    char buffer[MAXLINE+1];
    char buffer2[MAXLINE+1];
    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    while (1){
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        memset(buffer2,0,sizeof(buffer2));
        printf ("Enter a message \n");
        fgets(buffer,MAXLINE,stdin);
        send(sockfd,(char *)buffer,MAXLINE,0);
        printf ("Bufer is %s\n",buffer);
        if (strncmp(buffer,"exit",4)==0){
            printf ("Client exiting");
            exit(1);
        }
        recv(sockfd,(char *) buffer2,MAXLINE,0);
        printf ("Data received at client side is %s\n",buffer2);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

On running this code,I get a segmentation fault at the server side and receive no data at the client side. Can someone please explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I suppose the segmentation fault come from that line `send(clientfd,(char *)"Hello",MAXLINE,0);` on the server side code. The packet length should be sizeof("Hello"), In your code you are reading 1000+ bytes after en tail of your string.

Comment: @Bolo How does reading 1000+ extra bytes after tail of the string make a difference? I mean why should there be a segmentation fault because of it?

Comment: Hopelessly borked for multiple reasons. Just one: 'recv(clientfd,buffer,MAXLINE,0); ' called with clientfd unloaded, (hint -accept() returns something usefull).

Comment: @MartinJames I tried the code with clientfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,&len); but the code isn't still working, could you please let me know about the other errors

Comment: There are too many.  Look at other client/server questions in the 'sockets' tag.  Have one more freebie: take the listen() call out of the loop - you only need to call it once.

Comment: @MartinJames I spent a day thinking about errors, but couldn't find anything else other than what you mentioned. Please let me know what other errors are there in the code.

Comment: @MartinJames In case you don't have time, please give me link of the questions in the 'sockets' tag which you were refering to

Comment: @lovecoder1234 Because your are trying to read a portion of the memory that you doesn't have access to. If you want to understand why a segmentation fault could occur, do some research about "virtual memory".